# Correctly pool or start thread with wait or blocking in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, threadpool

I'm encountering an issue in an existing application where it seems variable data is being overwritten because a subroutine may be called from different threads.

I would like to make sure that each time the subroutine is called, from whichever thread that called it, it completes using it's current parameter values before running again with any new parameter values.

The subroutine called "WriteValueToTag" is in a Form class and accepts two parameters ByVal.

```
Private Function WriteValueToTag(ByVal PLCTagValue As Object, ByVal PLCTagName As Logix.Tag) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim retry As Integer = 1
        Dim result As Boolean = False
        Dim writeLock As New Object
        Do While retry < 3
            result = WriteToPLC(mPLC, PLCTagName)
            If (result) Then 'success
                Exit Do
            Else 'retry write to PLC
                retry += 1
                Log.Debug("  WriteToPLC failed - retry attempt #{0}", retry)
            End If
        Loop
        Return result
    Catch ex As Exception
        HandleError(ex, False)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

The subroutine calls a function (located in a module) called "WriteToPLC" and passes those parameters in ByRef.

```
Public Function WriteToPLC(ByRef PLC As Logix.Controller, ByRef PLCTag As Logix.Tag) As Boolean
```

I wasn't sure if simply adding a SyncLock around the WriteToPLC would work or I could somehow threadpool (queue) the calls to WriteToPLC so they occur in order, but I'm having issues trying to get the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem to work calling WriteToPLC since that function takes a two parameters and returns a boolean.

Would SyncLock be enough to solve this by allowing WriteToPLC to complete before the next call?

```
...
Dim writeLock As New Object
Do While retry < 3
   SyncLock writeLock
      result = WriteToPLC(mPLC, PLCTagName)
   End SyncLock
...
```

Any assistance and code examples on correctly threading/queuing this would be appreciated.

Comment: The data that is being overwritten, is it in the PLC, or in the PC?

Comment: Simply adding a `SyncLock` around the `WriteToPLC` call will not likely solve your issue.  I suspect that adding it around the entire try block won't either.  Can you post more of the code?  Specifically, the part that creates the thread pool thread and makes the call to `WriteValueToTag`

Comment: It's in the PC.  I took out logging code from my posted sample and I can see that my main UI thread calls this subroutine and on occasions it appears to simultaneously be called by another thread (2 threads hitting it) and I believe the variable values is being overwritten in the PC, so I get an error (NULL value error) in the WriteToPLC function. Thus my thinking was perhaps I need to thread this correctly or pool them.

Comment: @Wyatt Earp - there is no thread pooling now.  All calls made to WriteValueToTag are done from subroutines or functions in the Form class.  A typical call would be this WriteValueToTag(EnumStatusHandshake.PCReceivedMessage,  LoadAccepted)  Where the 1st paramaters is the message (like a 10, 20 , or 30) and the second parameter is defined as the PLC tag.  Not sure if I need to thread/pool the call to WriteValueToTag or just WriteToPLC which is called from WriteValueToTag?  And of course the correct way to do this.  I don't want to skip a WriteToPLC, just wait for prior one to be complete first.

Comment: You sure you can't use an OPC server? http://www.kepware.com/Products/products_OPCServers.asp They do the hard work of transferring the data back and forth, and can kick off events when certain tags change I believe.

Comment: @Jeremy - thank you Jeremy.  Unfortunately, I cannot use OPC at this time.  I need to resolve the code as-is right now.

Comment: I'm not seeing why your SyncLock wouldn't work. Do you know for certain that WriteToPLC is never called from anywhere else? If not, lock here should be fine.

Comment: @gienebob - WriteToPLC is not called from anywhere else.  I'll try the SyncLock and see what happens, but was thinking that correctly threading or pooling this would be a more correct solution.

Comment: If SyncLock does not fix it, then I doubt queuing to a work thread would either. Use the lock to fix/verify, THEN redesign if you feel the need.

Comment: So, if you're not kicking off new threads with the ThreadPool currently, where does the multithreading currently exist?  If all the messages are being run off the same thread, the SyncLock won't accomplish anything.

Comment: Also, slightly unrelated, your retry logic (depending on your latency to the controller) is probably not doing much.  Most .NET controls to write to a PLC, that I've worked with at least, write (and fail) in as little as 5ms.  Your logic would immediately retry 3 times in 15ms (in many cases).  I think you probably want to rethink the way that works.  (Or just remove it, and log the error)

Comment: @Wyatt Earp - There is a 3rd party control on the form (ModbusHeader control).  That control is declared at the form level and has events.  It seems to run on its own thread and when it fires an event, the event routine calls the WriteValueToTag.  I apologize for not mentioning this before. It seems the WriteValueToTag, when called from this control event is done so within the contents of that thread and not that of the form (even though the WriteValueToTag routine is in the form class).

Comment: @Wyatt Earp - thank you for the feedback on the retry logic.  I have seen in my log file where it does fail the write and is successful after attempt #2.  However, this happens very infrequently.  I will rethink the retry timing - perhaps add a slight 250-500ms delay.

Comment: So, in order to know if the `SyncLock` is going to fix anything, you should set a breakpoint in your `WriteValueToTag` method and find out if the thread is a new thread, or the same one everytime.  If it is always getting fired from the same thread, then a `SyncLock` will not do anything because it's running synchronously already.  (Unless you are also writing to the PLC from the UI thread as well)

Comment: Can you define the issue a little more?  Can you elaborate on what makes you think that it's a threading issue?

Comment: Also, I'd advise against a delay in the `WriteValueToTag` method because it will hold up the thread and can potentially hold up other events from firing...

Comment: @Wyatt Earp -  My logging shows me the calling threads.  See next comment for example (too long to post in one).

Comment: Log:  2015-06-03 03:55:06 [Info] ThreadID:1 RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast'=>'frmRun.MsgReceived'=>'frmRun.UpdateTrackingTable - Entering Sub UpdateTrackingTable()
2015-06-03 03:55:06 [Error] ThreadID:21 frmRun.WriteValueToTag'=>'modPLC.WriteToPLC'=>'modHelper.HandleError - Unexpected exception in Method WriteToPLC Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Tag.Name = IF_Lens[1].WO_ID  Value property is null
2015-06-03 03:55:06 [Trace] ThreadID:21 frmRun.mh_FlyerEOMStatus'=>'frmRun.WriteValueToTag'=>'modPLC.WriteToPLC - Entering Function WriteToPLC()

Comment: So, it looks like two of the writes to the PLC are both using the same Thread (ThreadID: 21).  It makes me think that all the writes are already happening on the same thread.  (Though it is a small sample size, you'd probably want to confirm that)  If that is the case, you don't have a threading issue.

Comment: @Wyatt Earp - Comments are too short to show more log data, but WriteValueToTag is happening on the main UI thread (ThreadID:1) while other writes are happening on ThreadID:21.  Here is the line in the log before those I posted (notice the time stamps are the same). Not sure what "RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast" means though!!  2015-06-03 03:55:06 [Debug] ThreadID:1 RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast'=>'frmRun.MsgReceived'=>'frmRun.WriteValueToTag - Entering Function WriteValueToTag()

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the locking object outside of the function for `SyncLock` to work correctly:

```
Private writeLock As New Object

Private Function WriteValueToTag(ByVal PLCTagValue As Object, ByVal PLCTagName As Logix.Tag) As Boolean

    SyncLock writeLock

        Try

        Catch

        End Try

    End SyncLock

End Function
```